# Getting error on passing argument to the code behind method using jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I don't know what's wrong with this code. I am not able to implement it properly. 
Thanks in advance for help.
This is what I've tried so far and stuck

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                for (var key in localStorage) {
                    GetQuickVL(key);
                }
            });
            function GetQuickVL(key) {
                if (key.substring(0, 4) == "vhs-") {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/QuickViewList.aspx/GetQuickVD",
                        data: '{key: ' +'1' + '}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: OnSuccess,
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.response);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            function OnSuccess(response) {
                alert('df');
            }
</script>
```

and the C-Sharp code is

```
[WebMethod]
public int GetQuickVD(int key)
{
    return key;
}
```

Comment: Is there any error in your console?

Comment: i'm getting a weird error but i can't post the image because I don't have 10 reputation points

Comment: @user3472352, no need to post the image - text of the error will suffice

Comment: i'm getting something like function () { if (u) { var t = u.length; (function i(t) { b.each(t, function (t, n) { var r = b.type(n); "function" === r ? e.unique && p.has(n) || u.push(n) : n && n.length && "string" !== r && i(n) }) })(arguments), n ? o = u.length : r && (s = t, c(r)) } return this }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the method is in your code behind (.aspx.cs file) try declaring the GetQuickVD method as static. so it's public static int GetQuickVD(int key).

Comment: i wonder if anyone can tell why I'm getting error on doing data:'{key:'+'1,1,1,1,'+'}';

Answer (score 1):

`key` is an `int`. You've passed it as a `string`:

```
'{key: ' +'1' + '}',
```

Either do:

```
{key: 1 },
```

Or make your web method take an `object` or `string` as its parameter:

```
[WebMethod]
public int GetQuickVD(object key)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(key);
}
```

Here is a complete working sample (I just tested this). Adapt to suit your needs:

WebService:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)] 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] // <- ** MAKE SURE THIS IS UNCOMMENTED!
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public int GetQuickVD(int key)
    {
        return key;
    }
}
```

Aspx page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.foo').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebService1.asmx/GetQuickVD",
                data: '{key: ' + '1' + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    alert("success");
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
<a href="#" class="foo">click me</a>
```

Comment: I've edited the answer with a fully working sample. It should be easy to plug the rest of your code in. Do you have this line: `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` uncommented or added to your web service? The `url` property in your ajax call looks a bit weird too. Can you post the code behind to that file? You should move your web method into its own webservice really.

Comment: The code of DGibbs looks good. Should work. Here's another example I've written about 2 years ago: http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/8/asp.net/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-a-webservice-asmx-method   I can't find any big difference. Maybe you have more luck or the problem is elsewhere